# rm -i inside a loop

Tags: bash

I have rm -i inside a for loop but when I run it, it prints the question ("do you want to delete this?) but doesn't stop to let me answer.

```
find .. -name "*.tex" | while read line; do
    printf "${line%%tex}""aux" | xargs rm -i
done
```

How do I fix this?

Also I was originally trying to do it by using exec like so

```
find ..-name "*.tex" -exec printf "${{}%%tex}""aux"\; | xargs rm -i
```

but I get the error "bad substitution".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux:

```
find .. -name "*.tex" | while read line; do
    rm -i "${line%%tex}aux" < /dev/tty
done
```

You don't need to use `xargs` if you have a single argument, but you do need to access the original tty somehow while inside the loop. The above works on Linux, there are probably similar tricks on other systems.

Another (possibly more portable) way to do this is to "save" `stdin` before entering the while  loop (assuming you're not using fd 9 for other purposes):

```
exec 9<&0
find .. -name "*.tex" | while read line; do
    rm -i "${line%%tex}aux" <&9
done
```

Difference between the two: the first one will always try (and possibly fail) to read from the controlling `tty`. The other one will read from whatever `stdin` was outside the loop.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem with question that can't be answered, does it?

Comment: quite right, forgot about the important part... (I think there's better than this tty redirect, but can't find it right now)

Comment: Thanks Mat, it works. But what exactly does the < /dev/tty do?

Comment: `/dev/tty` is "a synonym for the controlling terminal of a process" (`man 4 tty`). `foo < whatever` redirects the standard input of `foo` from "file" `whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS='
'
declare -a ar=($(find . -name '*.tex'))
IFS="$OIFS"
for x in "${ar[@]}"
 do
  rm -i "${x%%tex}aux"
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

If `find` isn't an absolute requirement, you can replace it with a simple glob:

```
for f in ../*.tex; do
    rm -i ${f%%tex}aux
done
```